# How to transfer Adobe licenses to another Mac

Tags: mac, license, adobe

A Power Mac just died at the office. We also have another one which died a couple of months ago. They both had Adobe software installed on them, and I need to transfer those licensees to other Macs.

Problem is, most of these Macs were transferred from another office, so we don't have any disks or licensing information - except what's on the hard drive. I was told that the IT guy that was here before me managed to transfer licensees just by copying some files. So I scoured the hard drives and managed to find some stuff which resembles licensing information, but I was wondering whether there are any guides on how to do this.

I would at least need the versions of the installed products, and their serial numbers. This information was requested by Adobe when I contacted them. I told them I would need to get that from the hard drives, but they weren't willing to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to find out if you had technical support services for those Adobe softwares? if yes then you can ask them for the version and serial numbers. If you are a company and you have volume licensing the information you are looking for is registered in the Adobe services. Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is we don't have any registration information - I don't know how they're registered (volume, retail) or whether they have technical support. I was hoping to recover as much information as possible from the HDDs, and the call Adobe and see how can the incenses be transferred.